# Wordpress - Blank pages and 200 http response on Debian using Nginx and php5

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm trying to start a Wordpress site on my Debian server, using Nginx and php5. I followed different tutorials but stuck : the server is responding [200 http](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) responses to any url typed from the domain name, mes-affaires doot xyz . My browser is showing a blank page, but no error too.

As the server is responding 200 responses I'm not getting any error log in the Nginx log files which is a problem to know what to do.

Any idea why it's showing a blank screen or how I could spot the current error?

Thanks

Comment: Wordpress is PHP 7 compatible, I would suggest using that. Your issue is that you should turn on error reporting in the php.ini

Comment: I noticed that you have solved the problem, consider to explain how you solve the problem or vote the answer that helped you, this helps the Stack Overflow community..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem can be caused by many factors:**

> **1.** A poorly configured nginx (Read Configuring Nginx)
>
> **2.** A permission problem (Read step 5 of Configuring Nginx)
>
> **3.** A missing php module that you can find out enabling PHP error_reporting (Read Pages are still blank? Php error_reporting
>   September)

### Configuring Nginx

Nginx works a little differently from Apache and if you do not use a management panel, the procedure is a bit complicated.

**1.** `sudo apt-get install nginx php5-fpm mysql mysql-dev` next activate mysql `sudo mysql_install_db`and run the setup script `sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation`

**2.** Create a folder in /var/www with your site name (mkdir mess-affaires)

**3.** go to /etc/nginx/sites-available and create a file with the same name as your domain (`touch mess-affaires.xyz`)

**4.** Open your new file with an editor (`nano mess-affaires.xyz`) and add these lines:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/mess-affaires;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name www.mess-affaires.xyz mess-affaires.xyz;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
    }
    location ~ .php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

**4.1.** After this you need to link it to your **sites-enabled** folder using:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mess-affaires.xyz /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mess-affaires.xyz
```

Nginx set a **default** file for example in your sites-available, delete it to avoid the "conflicting server name error":

```
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

**4.2.** Restart your nginx installation with `sudo service nginx restart`

**5.** Set permission to your folder `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/mess-affaires/` and make sure that everyone is able to read your new files `sudo chmod 755 /var/www` o to your folder /var/www/mess-affaires and upload the wordpress installation, now you see the website.

> If you still don't see anything, see the point 6

**6.** **If you do not see anything**, go to your terminal and type:

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/mess-affaires
```

### Configuring mysql/phpmyadmin with nginx

Wordpress is a web application that require a mysql database, go to install it!

**1.** `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`

**2.** `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /usr/share/nginx/html`

**3.** Now we must now allow the mcrypt module in php `sudo php5enmod mcrypt`

**4.** restart phpfpm `sudo service php5-fpm restart`

**5.** visit http://YOUR_SERVER_IP/phpmyadmin, log-in and create a new database for your wordpress installation

### Pages are still blank? Set php error_reporting

> If your pages are still blank, enable php [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

To do this you can try two ways:

#### Set error_reporting from your php files

Open your Wordpress index.php and put these lines to the very top of your page (after

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

#### Set error_reporting from php5-fpm.conf

Open with an editor your php5-fpm-conf, try one of these directories:

```
/etc/php-fpm.d/mydomain.conf
/etc/php-fpm.conf
```

If you sing my guide, you have not the native php installation but php5-fpm and you can configure your .conf file error params like this:

```
; enable display of errors
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_flag[display_startup_errors] = on
```

If you use a native php installation, set your config error_reporting like this:

```
; enable display of errors
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```